# How to prevent keys from removing due to duplication in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

(Please care to edit if came up with more concise thread title)

Is it possible at all?

I had three lists, merged them:

```
merged = {keys_[i]:[first_list[i], second_list[i]] for i in xrange(len(keys_))}
```

And since my list `keys_` had a few idential elements the lenght of dictionary has shrinked of the duplicated keys. I know dict keys can't be idencial but maybe there's some way around it?

**@ EDIT**

Responding to comments:

I'm just trying to merge three lists into a dict.

```
keys_ = ['100', '600', '100']
first_list = ['animals', 'cars', 'people']
second_list = ['cat', 'Fiat', 'John']
```

All I want to get is this:

```
merged = {'100': ['animals', 'cat'], '600': ['cars', 'Fiat'], '100': ['people', 'John']}
```

I want to keep all keys (both `100`) so prevent them from being overwritten.

Comment: What do you mean "some way around it"? No, there is no way around it, but there are other data structures that could be more suitable for you. We don't know what would work best because we don't know what problem you are solving.

Comment: May be you can use `collections.Counter` here, it'll keep track of the repeated keys. Better give us some examples.

Comment: @ Lev, I just want to merge my three lists into a dict. But the problem is, I want the keys to be elements of the list, some of which are idential. Ok, I'll edit the nitial post with an example.

Comment: if you need to retain all values for a key you might have to switch up your data structure... as @LevLevitsky mentioned you need ot provide more information.
perhaps:
`merged_dict['key'] = ['list', 'of', 'values']`

Comment: "I just want to merge my three lists into a dict". But why are you sure that's what you should do if none of the lists is unique?

Comment: I edited the initial post.

Comment: I'm afraid your edit didn't clear anything. What you show is impossible. You need another data structure. The choice of the data structure should depend on the way you will need to access the data. What should `merged['100']` be?

Comment: Note that simply typing your expected value of `merged` into the interpreter indicates the flaw in your plan

Comment: Yes, thanks guys for your help. It was not the greatest of the questions.

Comment: Your first sentence is kind of a tragedy. Remember, the first few sentences of your question are what people see when they mouse over your question on the front page, which they are more likely to do when your title is unclear. Make them count. This way both your title is bad and your question intro is unhelpful.

Comment: Actually, the more mistakes you make the faster you learn. I kind of apply this strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this : Each repeated key contains it's values in the form of list of lists.

```
In [12]: from collections import defaultdict

In [13]: dic=defaultdict(list)

In [14]: for a,b,c in zip(keys_,first_list,second_list):
    dic[a].append([b,c])
   ....:     

In [15]: dic
Out[15]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
{'100': [['animals', 'cat'], ['people', 'John']],
 '600': [['cars', 'Fiat']]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing your problem, here is what might be useful for you:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in chain(first_list.iteritems(), second_list.iteritems()):
    merged[key].append(value)
```

If the dictionaries are `{1: 11}` and `{1: 21, 2: 22}` this code would produce `{1: [11, 21], 2:[22]}`.

Answer (score 1):

We see similar problems when we are working with csv files where the first row values are significant for one reasons or another.  If I were working with this I would try very hard to consider whether or not this data structure is the most useful and will be persistent for you across time.  If it is and if you just have to have a dictionary then I would do something like the following

```
from collections import defaultdict:
myDict = default_dict(list)
keys_ = ['100', '600', '100']
first_list = ['animals', 'cars', 'people']
second_list = ['cat', 'Fiat', 'John']

for numb, key in enumerate(keys_):
    unique = str(numb)
    myDict[key + '_' + unique ].append(first_list[numb])
    myDict[key + '_' + unique ].append(second_list[numb])
```

The problem with this though is that you really can't generalize.  I am not a great programmer but I really do try to think how can I make this problem more general so the next time I see a problem somewhat similar to this I already know the answer.  This would take a lot of work to apply it to the next case.

This does not give you exactly what you want but you can process your keys and split them on the underscore if they are significant if they are not significant you can use them as is.

If we have something like this I usually add a new key, and it is just the index number for the position of the item in the list

```
{0:['100','animals',cat], 1:['600','cars','Fiat'], 2:['100','People','John']}
```

We have to do this sometimes when reading in CSV files generated by others this is the case when the 'real' column headings are spread across two or more rows

But this solution and my earlier solution at least requires that the list be of equal length (missing values indicated by a blank of some sort and this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary of lists is the usual approach.

You could probably also use a duptreap:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/
This module comes with a unique key-dict-like interface, but also a version that allows duplicate keys.

HTH